# How to change URL at runtime

Tags: cobalt

We are trying to use Cobalt (20.stable) browser as the browser of our web SPA application.
My requirement is to be able to change URL at runtime, what I was able to find in the code:
Is:

```
  starboard::shared::starboard::Application::Link(const char* link_data)
```

which ends up sending:

```
 kSbEventTypeLink
```

Unfortunately this is not working, as code is ignoring the call; the handling reaches the point:

```
  // TODO: Remove this when terminal application states are properly handled.
  if (deep_link_event->IsH5vccLink()) {
    browser_module_->Navigate(GURL(deep_link_event->link()));
  }
```

In my case I m trying to change the URL to let say https://www.example.com.
There should be a way to do that as when navigating we can always have a link that will cause the browser to go to some URL?

Answer (score 0):

Porting layer is not supposed to control navigation directly. Instead, your Starboard implementation may send a deep link event which could be intercepted by a web app which will perform a navigation. See `h5vcc_runtime.idl` for Web API.

That said, if you are building an SPA, why do you even need to change a URL? Initial URL of a web app is controlled by `--url` command line switch.

Comment: Thanks!
> Starboard implementation may send a deep link event |
That what I did, but in my case I m setting URL: https://www.example.com
This ends up it the code I mentioned above, checking IsH5vccLink() and call Navigate(). For https://www.google.com, IsH5vccLink() is false, and the navigation is not done (Deeplink event is ignored).
Should I make H5vccLink out of https://www.example.com?
Please advice
> why do you even need to change a URL?|
For development purpose we need to switch to other urls (other apps) without having to kill the cobalt browser and start an new one with new URL.

Answer (score 0):

When you say runtime are you looking to change the initial URL when the app is first launched? If so, you could just use the `--url` parameter.

So you could do the following:
`cobalt --url="https://www.example.com"`

Comment: I want to do that after the application is started. Let say I start with: cobalt --url="https://www.app1.com". Then later in my App1 I wont to switch to another https://www.app2.com. (just if there is a link with href="https://www.app2.com" is clicked).
Posting a deeplinkEvent with https://www.app2.com, is ignored due the the failing IsH5vccLink() test. (Forcing a Navigate() call gives nothing).

Answer (score 0):

I did a patch to allow changing the URL.
I just need to call starboard::shared::starboard::Application::Link("https://www.example.com").
Inside this call a DeepLinkEvent is posted.
Patch : https://gofile.io/?c=9GvNHX

Answer (score 0):

Cobalt does not navigate for you. The JavaScript receives the deeplink with the function it sets on `h5vcc.runtime.onDeepLink` and then does whatever it wants with that. As a SPA, it will parse the URL and load new content from its server in its own internal data format (e.g. [protocol buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers), JSON, etc.) which it uses to update its own DOM to show new content.

Navigating is not the point of a SPA since that makes it not be a *single page* application. However, there may be cases such as a loader app that will want to make some initial decisions then load the actual SPA. That loader app would have to have the appropriate CSP rules in place, then set `window.location` to the URL of the page to navigate to.

***Note:** The code you found in [Application::OnDeepLinkEvent()](https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/refs/heads/19.lts.1+/src/cobalt/browser/application.cc#990) is a remnant that previously supported the [H5vccURLHandler](https://cobalt.googlesource.com/cobalt/+/refs/heads/19.lts.1+/src/cobalt/browser/h5vcc_url_handler.cc), which was removed in Cobalt 20. It's not meant to navigate to arbitrary deeplinks.*